# Solving a system of nonlinear differential equations with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve the following:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = yt^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = xt^2$$
Given initial conditions $x(0)=y(0)=1$?

Comment: Have you learnt matrix exponentials?

Comment: I haven't, is that required for this solution?

Comment: You might be able to take derivatives and back substitute I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The product gives

$$y\frac{dy}{dt}=x\frac{dx}{dt}$$

and

$$y^2(t)=x^2(t)$$

or  $$y(t)= x(t).$$

thus

$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dt}=t^2$$

$\implies$

$$y(t)= e^\frac{t^3}{3}=x(t)$$

Comment: If you use the initial conditions to find $C=0$ in $x^2=y^2+C$, then you can also use them to exclude $y(t)=-x(t)$ and also to find $.λ=1$.

Comment: @LutzL Yes you're right thanks.

Comment: Thanks. When we integrate in the second step, where is the constant $C$?

Comment: @user135237 $C=0$ since $x(0)=y(0)$

Answer (score 1):

Set $x(t)=X(t^3)$, $y(t)=Y(t^3)$. Then
$$
x'(t)=X'(t^3)3t^2=Y(t^3)t^2\\
y'(t)=Y'(t^3)3t^2=X(t^3)t^2\\
$$ 
and the squares of $t$ cancel to the linear system with constant coefficients in $s=t^3$, $t=\sqrt[3]s$
$$
X'(s)=\frac13Y(s)\\
Y'(s)=\frac13X(s)
$$

Comment: How can we find for x and y in terms of t?

Comment: For instance by computing $X''(s)=\frac13 Y'(s)=\frac19X(s)$.